# How does this canvas paint method slow down my app so badly?

Tags: java, android, performance, canvas

I have recently encountered the problem that the `canvas.drawArc()`-method on my locked SurfaceView canvas significantly slows down the loading and resuming time of my app. I am absolutely sure that the annotated line of code mainly causes this problem, but I also attached some other code that might be relevant for you.

The thread which is created in the `surfaceView.surfaceCreated()`-method *(probably less relevant)*:

```
while(true) {
    while (!running()) {
        try {
            sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
    }

    try {
        surfaceView.canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized(holder) {
            surfaceView.draw();
        }
    } catch(Exception ignore) {

    } finally {
        try {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(surfaceView.canvas);
        } catch(Exception ignore) {

        }
    }
}
```

And the actual `draw()`-method which is most likely to cause the problem:

```
// other draw methods, including a bitmap, ovals from float[]-Arrays, paths and text

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(0x33d0d5c9);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

ArrayList<float[]> particles = new ArrayList<>();
while(particles.size() < 200) {
    particles.add(new float[]{x1, y1, x2, y2});
}

// completely removing the following loop prevents the problem
for(float[] p : particles) {
    // draw overlapping particles on the canvas (a path would affect the look)
    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]), paint);
}
```

I would really appreciate your suggestions on how to optimize my code to work properly.

**EDIT:** My solution based on [lukasrozs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273651/4734360)

```
final Canvas canvas = canvas;
Thread particleThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RectF rect = new RectF();
        for(float[] p : particles) {
            rect.set(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
            canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
        }
    }
});
particleThread.start();

// some stuff

try {
    particleThread.join();
} catch(Exception ignore) {

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the content of your draw method ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I hope that my edit answers your question. If not, I would need to search through a lot of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `ArrayList` and `float[]` at all. Also, you don't have to initialize/construct `new RectF` every time.

```
// other draw methods, including a bitmap, ovals from float[]-Arrays, paths and text

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(0x33d0d5c9);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

RectF rect = new RectF();
for(int i = 0; i < 200) {
    rect.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
}
```

If you can, you should execute this method in another thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){void run(){
    // draw all the ovals on canvas
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){void run(){
        // this will be executed in main thread when drawing finishes
    }});
}}).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you are creating to many objects in your onDraw method. Try to move the creation of the particles outside (in the constructor, or just do it once), and only set the new x,y and size values in the draw method.

Creating new objects in the onDraw method also increases the risk of the garbage collector to be triggered, so its best to avoid it ...